# Density gradient vs. entropy of mixing

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, kinetic-theory-of-gases

I was wondering how real gases would behave when they are released into a closed container with fixed volume.

For example, suppose we use chlorine and nitrogen gas. Obviously, chlorine has a higher density than nitrogen gas. Now suppose both are released in similar quantities into a container without air, we have a closed system.

From what I remember for ideal gases, they should mix because the entropy of mixing increases overall entropy. However, since the real gases have different densities and gravity is working on them, the nitrogen gas should be on top of the chlorine gas because of buoyancy.

For reference, mixing of liquids is easy to predict, for example water and ethanol mix because intermolecular interactions dominate and buoyancy does not. But what is up with gases?

Which effect prevails here? Or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because of entropy of mixing, each gas fully distributes itself through the container.  Assuming ideality, each gas's distribution is independent of the presence of the other gas (neither gas "sees" the other).  This distribution, however, is subject to a Boltzmann gravity gradient: $\rho(h) = \rho(0) e^{\frac{-m g h}{RT}}$.  And since their masses are different, their distributions will be different: the density of the heavier gas will fall off more rapidly with elevation.   You can actually calculate what will happen to the composition of the mixture as a function of height.

Comment: Note that this assumes no turbulent mixing. You should do this calculation yourself.  You will see the change is composition is extremly small unless the column of gas is very tall.

Comment: @theorist Good comment! Note that T=T(h), for air at equilibrium it is dT/dh = -0.0098 K/m, Air with constant initial temperature will reach such T gradient at the equilibrium ( much faster than forming composition gradient).

Comment: @Poutnik  Thanks ;).  Note that the OP wasn't asking about open air, they were asking about air in a container, which presumably is building-sized or smaller.  Thus I don't think we don't need to concern ourselves with atmospheric temperature gradients.  The idea here is that if the OP does the calculation for any reasonably-sized container, they will see (as you know) that the gravitational gradient has only a miniscule effect.

Comment: @theorist It is not related specifically to atmosphere, which is just another, giant and open container. The point is, if you apply the Boltzmann formula for high enough container to have some noticable composition change, you cannot ignore temperature gradient either, but T(h) must be integrated in the computation. BUT I do agree that for the rough first picture, it is more than enough.

Comment: @Poutnik  Are you referrng to Tolman temperature gradients in a gravitational field, which are reported here to be a consequence of General Relativity?  Information on this phenomenon is sparse, so I don't know whether it is generally accepted https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5852e579be659442a01f27b8/t/5af9c04faa4a993b554df0e9/1526317136980/Santiago_Visser_2018.pdf

Comment: @theorist No, I mean the standard adiabatic mixing. Random fluctuations warm up lower layers and cool down upper layers until about 0.98 K/100 m is established. If it was mixed turbulently, it would be established quickly.

Comment: @Poutnik It sounds like you have in mind a different type of system from what I'm considering. Here's what I had in mind, which I think corresponds to what the OP was asking:  Suppose you have a large box of gas sitting in lab and maintained *at thermodynamic equilibrium*. The box contains two non-interacting gases, one light and one heavy. You want to know how the composition of the gas will change as you move from the bottom of the box (h=0 m) to the top (say, h = 3 m).  Outside of a hypothetical GR-based Tolman effect, how would gravity create a temp gradient in a sys at thermo equilibrium?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133861/discussion-between-poutnik-and-theorist).

Answer (score 1):

There would be (non-measurable on small scale) molar fraction gradient (Density gradient is always present due hydrostatic compression).

At this state, the rate of chlorine/nitrogen gravitational settling down/up is balanced by the diffusive mixing driven by molar fraction gradient.